# Not getting desire SQL output with inner query

Tags: sql, subquery, case

`Table-1`: `NominationPeriods`

```
----------------------
Id Period  Status    
----------------------
1  9       Unlocked                 
3  8       locked   
----------------------
```

`Table-2` : `NominationRevisions`

```
-------------------------------------------
Id Revision  Period  Status  
-------------------------------------------
15  1         9        M      
19  2         9        R      
20  3         9        A      
--------------------------------------------
```

`Query`:

```
SELECT Period
        ,nomper.STATUS
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN (
                        (
                            SELECT (
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN STATUS IN ('P','A')
                                            THEN 'TRUE'
                                        ELSE 'FALSE'
                                        END
                                    )
                            FROM NominationRevisions
                            WHERE revision = (
                                    SELECT max(revision)
                                    FROM NominationRevisions
                                    WHERE Period = nomper.Period
                                    )
                                AND NomPeriodNbr = nomper.Period
                            ) = 'TRUE'
                        )
                    THEN 'TRUE'
                ELSE 'FALSE'
                END
            ) AS Flag
    FROM NominationPeriods nomper
```

`Expected Output`:

```
-------------------------------------
Period  Status     Flag
-------------------------------------
9       Unlocked   TRUE
8       locked     TRUE
-------------------------------------
```

`Actual Output`:

```
-------------------------------------
Period  Status     Flag
-------------------------------------
9       Unlocked   TRUE
-------------------------------------
```

I want all  NominationPeriods list as output having

1. Highest Revision of the Period is 'A' or 'P' then Flag=TRUE
2. If no Revision found for a period then also return Flag=TRUE

Comment: it is because  your subquery returning only one result in your where clause.

Comment: As @SuchitKumar noted the subquery ill not return for period 8 because there's no row for that period in second table. Try to rewrite it using joins instead so you can use a outter join

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select "Period", "Status",
       Coalesce((select top 1 case when r."Status" in ('A', 'P') then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end from NominationRevisions r where p.Period = r.Period  order by r.Revision desc), 'TRUE') "Flag"
from NominationPeriods p
```

Now I believe it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this might work for you, using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    np.*, 
    COALESCE(
        IF( nr.`Status` IS NULL, 'TRUE', NULL),
        IF(nr.`Status` IN ('A', 'R'), 'TRUE', NULL),
        'FALSE'
    ) AS 'Flag'
FROM nominationperiods np
LEFT JOIN nominationrevisions nr ON 
    np.Period = nr.Period 
    AND nr.Revision = (SELECT MAX(nr.Revision)
                       FROM nominationrevisions nr
                       WHERE nr.Period = np.Period)
```

The join takes `max` revision only, and then uses `coalesce()` to test all conditions for `true`, with a fallback to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrited your query with less cases and in a didatic manner. See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0711/4) for a working example usind the data your provided.

The point is: Return all Nomination Period but only set flag to **TRUE** if the **last revision** got an **A** or **P** status.

```
select nomper.Period, nomper.Status
,case when
  (
    exists
    (
      select 1
      from dbo.[NominationRevisions] nr
      join 
        (
          select max(nr0.Revision) as MaxRevision, nr0.Period
          from dbo.[NominationRevisions] nr0
          group by nr0.Period
        ) as nr1 on nr1.Period = nr.Period
                    and nr1.MaxRevision = nr.Revision
       where nr.Status = 'A' or nr.Status = 'P'
    )
  )
  then 'TRUE'
  else 'FALSE'
end
from dbo.[NominationPeriods] nomper
```